# Can't give kids stolen toys

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I enter the dialogue to give my adopted kid a gift, but the **toy sword** and **child's doll** that are in my inventory don't display in the list.

Admittedly they are stolen. Is this the problem? Should I fence them, buy back and retry?

Comment: Fence them? You should return them to the poor children you stole them from, criminal scum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was because they were stolen. Fencing the item, then buying them back removed the "stolen" tag and the children accepted them.

This isn't [mentioned](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Adoption#Gifts_and_Allowance) in the wiki.